# Amplify Appsync auth depending on user role

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am making a Team like database. I want all members of the team to have `read` access, but ultimately each team member will have different permissions.

I set up my team table like:

```
type Team
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "admins", operations: [create, update, delete] }])
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "members", operations: [read, update] }])  {
  id: ID!
  teamID: ID!
  userID: ID!
  permissions: UserPermission!
  admins: [User!]!
  members: [User]
}
```

I was hoping to have some type of query or function that adds admins or members to the database depending on the current user role. I have a `TeamUserConnection` table, but I wasn't sure if I should be doing this through that table or the resolver. Any help would be awesome!